# why I have got such kind of BarButton one upon other?

Tags: ios4, uibarbuttonitem

[image]

Hi!I have used UIBarButton Image but i have got such kind of issue.i mean Image+button on backside.for that i have written code below.

UIBarButtonItem *btnMap = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapbutton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnMapClicked:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnMap;
    [btnMap release];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use initWithCustomView and set a UIButton as the customView instead:

```
UIButton *subBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
subBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40);  //adjust as needed
[subBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mapbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMapClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btnMap = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:subBtn];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnMap; 
[btnMap release];
```

Note that the sender in btnMapClicked: will now be a UIButton instead of a UIBarButtonItem.